# Understanding Sylow's First Theorem Using Double Cosets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, sylow-theory

[Remark on Double Cosets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2xbz.jpg)

[Sylow's First Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQhKF.jpg)

**The above hyperlinks are on the proof I'm referring to.**

The above is the proof of: ***All Sylow $p$-groups are conjugate***.

**It is assumed**: *Let $G$ be a finite group such that $|G| = p^{n}q$, where $p$ is prime and $gcd(p,q) = 1$.*

I don't understand the proof from the following line: $|AxB| = p^{2n-m}$, where $2n-m \geq n + 1$. Since $p^{n+1} \nmid |AxB|$ $\forall x \in G$.

How is this so?

Since, how I understand the above line is: that since $2n-m \geq n + 1$ then $p^{n+1} | |AxB|$  $\forall x \in G$ and since $|G| = p^{n}q$ where $p^{n}$ is the highest power of $p$ that divides $G$, and from this we get our contradiction!

Thanks in advance for the kind help!

Comment: If I've read it correctly, then I think it is a typo.  I think it should be, $p^{n+1}$ *divides* $\mid AxB\mid$, rather than *not divides*, since that was indeed the point of the sentences that came before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source sentence has poor placement of the negation. Where it says

**Since $p^{n+1} \nmid |AxB|$ for every $x \in G$ $\ldots$**

one should read

**Since it is $\underline{\textbf{not true}}$ that $p^{n+1} \mid |AxB|$ for every $x \in G$ $\ldots$**

or better yet

**Since it is not true that $\forall x\in G\left(\;p^{n+1} \mid |AxB|\; \right)$ $\ldots$**

The correction suggested in the original post clears up the ambiguity in this sentence.